# How to print stream of stdout to a window using zenity or yad?

Tags: bash, shell-script, gtk, zenity, yad

Tools like [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) and [yad](https://github.com/v1cont/yad/) are gtk-based dialog makers used to create user-interfaces from shell scripts.

How to print the live stream of the output of piped commands to a window using those tools?

I tried this:
`cmd1 | zenity --text-info`
But when I close the zenity window, cmd1 is still running.
Also `cmd1 | cmd2 | zenity --text-info` doesn't work at all (nothing is printed).
Same with `yad`.

In short, I want a gtk window that shows the live output of `cmd1 | cmd2`, and closing the window, should quit `cmd1 | cmd2`

Comment: @Quasímodo cmd2 is awk in my case